# Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am building a multi authentication system using laravel 5.5. I have Admin and AdminRole Models as well as they respective migrations.There is one to one relationship between the Admin and AdminRole Models. Everything works fine. But when i tried to access the admin_role like so:

$admin->adminRole->name; It throws an error like so:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admin_roles.admin_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `admin_roles` where `admin_roles`.`admin_id` = 1 and `admin_roles`.`admin_id` is not null limit 1)'.

I have tried for many hours but could not be able to figure out what the problem is. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Admin.php Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'ip_address',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function adminRole() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AdminRole');
    }
}
```

admins.php migrations

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('admin_role_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->ipAddress('ip_address')->nullable();
            $table->string('photo')->default('avatar.png');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(true);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
}
```

AdminRole.php Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AdminRole extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function admin()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Admin');
    }

}
```

admin_role.php migrations

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdminRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admin_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admin_roles');
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite strange. Your relationship definitions are right. Does anything change if you explicitly specify the foreign key? `return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AdminRole', 'admin_role_id');`

Comment: I have also tried to specify the foreign key; but the problem remain the same

Comment: I have replicated your setup [here](https://implode.io/OCejjP). It's working. Can we see your controller/blade where you are doing the relationship call?

Comment: I am testing on tinker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was actually correct, i cleared my cache and reboot my system. It is working now. Thank you guys.